# Problem with UniServerZ,web server doesn't recognize/translate PHP showing pages in code

Tags: php, wamp

me and some colleagues are having installing this project on some PCs,some colleagues just unzip the folder with unzip the folder with `UniServerZ` and it runs wonderfully,on others',like my PC it doesn't work:

At first `UniServer` failed to start `apache` without giving an error log,but i figured out that i had to uninstall the current version of `Visual C++` Redistributable and install the 2012 version cause I'm actually running the project in `PHP 5.6`. Now `Uniserver` successfully starts `apache` but doesn't load `PHP`...I want to fix this problem cause everyone are using `Uniserver`,alternatively I'll try with `wamp`.

EDIT: I tried adding php 5.6 to PATH,and it now shows correctly my phpinfo.php file,but still doesn't work for phpMyAdmin...I guess the problem comes from the webserver

Comment: is PhP installed?

Comment: Have I to install it even globally? I have PHP 5.6 and 7.1 version in my Uniserver folder,under core. Also,do I need to add the folder the the system variables?